# Laravel 5.6 barryvdh dompdf version 0.8.4 show Indian Rupee symbol as "?"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

In one of my Laravel 5 project, I have used barryvdh dompdf (version 0.8.4) to generate PDF files. I used the following for meta e.g. `<meta charset="utf-8">` and in html code, I used to show the Indian Rupee symbol e.g. `<div style="font-size: 16px;">Payment of &#8377;  6000.</div>`
(&#8377 ; = html unicode of INR)

The PDF generates well however, the INR symbol is showing as `?`. From several sources, I see that they are using `dejavu` font. I have used the same

`<style>
  body { font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif; }
</style>`

However by using the dejaVu, the other text including INR sign in the PDF are showing garbage characters. Any help?

PS - Should I download the font and store it into the `asests/` folder?

Comment: `DejaVu` font dones't seems to know the `₹` symbol. You need to find one that support this character.

Comment: @cbaconnier https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/fontsupport.htm - Isee these font supports INR symbol. Can I use any one of it?

Comment: @cbaconnier your comment is conflicting with the answer of BrianS - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830914/inr-currency-symbol-on-pdf-using-dompdf

Comment: I don't know much about Indian characters. I tested ₹ in **Test drive**  of https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/dejavu-sans and it doesn't work.

Comment: Your code should work. Is the other text correctly displayed using the DejaVu font? You can visually confirm by falling back to a different family (e.g. `font-family: DejaVu Sans, monospace;`). Does Dompdf have write access to storage/fonts (see [issue #269}(https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/269))? Any errors logged?

Answer (score 2):

Add code inside of html tag

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <style>
            * { font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif; }
        </style>
```