# laravel-dompdf is not showing special character

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I am using "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf" package. I want to show different country's money symbol like ৳, ₹, € etc. When I put these type of symbols, in the output there only showing "?" question mark. On the other hand $(dollar) symbol work perfectly.

What is the solution it is ?

Comment: Try this [Currency Symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830914/inr-currency-symbol-on-pdf-using-dompdf)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INR currency symbol on pdf using dompdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830914/inr-currency-symbol-on-pdf-using-dompdf)

Comment: Similar but there also talk only about indian currency symbol but I need for all others symbol. That means when I input  ৳, ₹, € etc. in output, it will be shown  ৳, ₹, € beside money as like  ৳ 100.

Answer (score 1):

Now to place Rupee Symbol place the following code, in place of requirement
`<span style="font-family: DejaVu Sans; sans-serif;">₹</span>`